# Как создать из массива ключей создать многомерный объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Не знаю как точно описать задачу, поэтому лучше покажу на примере:
допустим есть массив `['first', 'second', 'third']` и значение `x`;

нужно получить вот такой объект с большой вложенностью:

```
{
 first: {
   second: {
      third: x
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ключи должны быть вложенные?

Comment: @T0xee.n17 получается да, каждый следующий элемент массива, влаживается как объект в предыдущий элемент массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для преобразования массива в многомерный объект, можно воспользоываться методом **reduceRight**

```js
const arrTemplate = ['first', 'second', 'third', '1', '2', '3'];
const x = 'value'

function toObj(arr, z) {
  return arr.reduceRight((acc, item) => ({[item]: acc}), z)
}

console.log(toObj(arrTemplate, x))
```

Comment: Опередили меня [на 1 минуту](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoArK.png). :)

Comment: Не, ну ваше право. Теперь я должен снести ответ.

Comment: @eccs0103 Я не специально :)

Answer (score 0):

Подобная задача решается рекурсивно. В данном случае, я полагаю, оптимальным подходом будет переписывание объекта в сам же объект, под следующим ключом, начиная с последнего ключа (самый вложенный объект) и кончая первым.

```js
let keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

let obj = {};

obj[keys.pop()] = 123;

for(key of keys.reverse())
  obj = {[key]: obj}
  
  
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: фан факт: [использование функций не проходит бесследно...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn9LH.png) (отслеживание скорости выполнения на примере 1 млн запросов с вложенностью 8 уровня)